# How can I show an element depending on selected option in a dropdown

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have created 3 cards in Angular from an object array. one of the properties of the objects is "price". if I wanted to include a select element, with 2 options, one of them saying "lower than 2000" and the other saying "bigger that 2000",

What would be the best way to show only the elements with a higher price of ..for example, 2000?

this is the HTML I've done:

```
<div class="mat-card-wrapper">
    <mat-card *ngFor="let person of dataArray; let i= index">
        <mat-card-title-group>
            <mat-card-subtitle>
                <span class="boldy">BookingId:</span>
                <span>
                    {{person.bookingId}}
                </span>
                <span class="boldy"> Cliente:</span>
                <span>
                    {{person.locationId.tutenUser.firstName +" "+
                    person.locationId.tutenUser.lastName}}
                </span>
                <span class="boldy">Fecha de Creación</span>
                <span>{{person.bookingTime}}</span>
                <span class="boldy">Dirección</span>
                <span>{{person.locationId.streetAddress}}</span>
                <span class="boldy">Precio</span>
                <span>{{person.bookingPrice}}</span>
            </mat-card-subtitle>
        </mat-card-title-group>
    </mat-card>
</div>
```

This generates 3 cards, I can't come out with the right way of adding a simple `<selec>` method that allow me to show only the elements with a price bigger than 2000 and the ones lower than 2000.

I know this is a very basic question but I'm stuck, can anyone help me with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a pipe to your ngFor which would filter your data depending on what you selected (<2000 or >2000).

```
<mat-card *ngFor="let person of dataArray | myfilterPipe:myCondition">
```

Your pipe would look like something like that:

```
 import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'myfilterPipe',
})
export class MyFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[], filter: condition): any {
        if (!items || !filter) {
            return items;
        }
        if(condition === over2000) {
           return items.filter(item => item.price > 2000);
        }
        if(condition === under2000) {
           return items.filter(item => item.price < 2000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: condition should be an enum or something like that. To test faster, you can use a number directly, 1 = over2000 and 2 = under2000

Comment: The pipe should be in its own file and added to the provider in your module file.

Comment: I'm reading about Angular pipes and I can see that `filter: condition` is a parameter, but I can 't figure out what "condition" is. Is it a type? I was reading about angular types and didn't find any `condition` type

Comment: It's not a type, that's just an example, pass the parameter you want as long as it works. It could be an enum (0 = over2000, 1 = under2000) which would be selected by your dropdown then it would be passed to your pipe and that way the pipe knows what it needs to return.

Comment: when doing this: `<mat-card *ngFor="let person of dataArray | myfilterPipe:myCondition">`, I get my condition underlined in red and it says "Identifier myCondition is not defined", can you please tell me why this happens? Thanks!

Comment: It's a variable that you need to assign in your ts file